# Mysql query how to avoid rows nulls/empty fields while doing left join

Tags: mysql

I have tried a query in mysql which works fine as:

```
SELECT medias.id,medias.hash,medias.customid,medias.timestamp,medias.uploaded,
       medias.data_updated, mediadetails.media_id, mediadetails.city,
       mediadetails.state_province, mediadetails.postal_code 
  FROM medias 
  LEFT JOIN mediadetails ON medias.id=mediadetails.media_id  
 ORDER BY medias.data_updated DESC 
 LIMIT 5;
```

[image]

Now I am trying to get those rows which do not have empty city/state_provice/postal_code.

Tried this :

```
SELECT medias.id, medias.hash,medias.customid, medias.timestamp,medias.uploaded,
       medias.data_updated, mediadetails.media_id, mediadetails.city,
       mediadetails.state_province, mediadetails.postal_code 
  FROM medias 
  LEFT JOIN mediadetails on  medias.id=mediadetails.media_id  
 ORDER BY medias.data_updated DESC
 WHERE medias.city<>'' 
   AND medias.state_province<>'' 
   AND medias.postal_code<>'' 
 LIMIT 5;
```

However getting error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where medias.city<>'' and medias.state_province<>'' and medias.postal_code<>'' l' at line 1
```

Can I get help on how to do it?

Comment: `ORDER BY` should be **after** `WHERE`.

Comment: I also suspect based on the columns you are selecting that your **WHERE** clause is specifying the wrong table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Empty* usually means `null`. 
In this case don't compare the column value to `''`, but use `IS NOT NULL`.
In any case, you can use [`coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT 
  medias.id, medias.hash,medias.customid, medias.timestamp, 
  medias.uploaded, medias.data_updated, 
  mediadetails.media_id, mediadetails.city,
  mediadetails.state_province, mediadetails.postal_code 
FROM medias INNER JOIN mediadetails 
ON  medias.id=mediadetails.media_id  
WHERE 
  COALESCE(mediadetails.city, '') <>'' 
  AND 
  COALESCE(mediadetails.state_province, '') <>'' 
  AND
  COALESCE(mediadetails.postal_code, '') <>'' 
ORDER BY mediadetails.data_updated DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Although this would work in most cases:

```
WHERE 
  mediadetails.city IS NOT NULL 
  AND 
  mediadetails.state_province IS NOT NULL 
  AND
  mediadetails.postal_code IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume your **WHERE** clause meant to reference table **mediadetails**. An observations: A NULL field when compared with any value will never compare TRUE. Thus, your **WHERE** clause will only select columns from the **meidadetails** table for non-NULL (and non-empty) values for the specified columns and the MySQL optimizer will replace your **OUTER JOIN** with an **INNER JOIN**. You might as well make it explicit:

```
SELECT medias.id, medias.hash,medias.customid, medias.timestamp,medias.uploaded,
       medias.data_updated, mediadetails.media_id, mediadetails.city,
       mediadetails.state_province, mediadetails.postal_code 
  FROM medias 
  INNER JOIN mediadetails on  medias.id=mediadetails.media_id  
 WHERE mediadetails.city <>'' 
   AND mediadetails.state_province <>'' 
   AND IFNULL(mediadetails.postal_code <>'' 
 ORDER BY mediadetails.data_updated DESC
 ;
```